# Scroll margin in buffers list

Tags: helm, scrolling

Setting `(setq smooth-scroll-margin 10)` with the `smooth-scrolling` package enables the introduction of a scroll margin, which has the advantage of avoiding jumps when the cursor reaches the end of the visible area (the first or last lines being displayed), which in turn makes the lines easier to track when scrolling with the keyboard.

How can we achieve the same behavior in the buffers list, typically invoked by typing `C-x b` (`helm-mini` in my case)? The `smooth-scroll-margin` variable seems to have no effect there.